# Looking for auto C code generation tools

Tags: c

I am working on embedded project that requires almost same kind of code template for each new implementation.
Instead of doing manual code, I am thinking to automate the code generation process.
So that I only need to provide input data to the tool in some format (could be any input format) and it generated C code according to it.
Open source would be the first choice but proprietary tools are also acceptable.

I already searched for Eclipse Modeling plugins Acceleo and Actifsource but didn't find them suitable for Embedded C code generation.
And I don't want to use heavy solution like MATLAB and LabVIEW just for code generation.

Answer (score 1):

C code generation from UML models is possible with tools such as:

- [IBM Rational Rhapsody](http://www-142.ibm.com/software/products/us/en/ratirhapfami)
- Open source Eclipse plugin [Topcased](http://www.topcased.org/)

Answer (score 0):

There are many variants of C code generation:

- function pointers (parent function do the same code exept a little variant)
- inline functions + macro (parameters of macro could define a new functions)
- systems like make, cmake, autotools (you write an input-file wich is modified at precompiling)

Tell more if you want to get more detailed answer.

Comment: can you clarify how autotools can help (if I am not wrong, you are taking about autoconf, automake).

Comment: I am aware of make but not much familiar with autotools.
Infect I am right now looking for autogen that is quite hard to get started and not much examples are available.

Comment: I meant conditional code generation: you make file.c.in which contains some code and some wariables, automake would substitute variables by their values. This isn't a code-generation as topic-starter means, but source files may be created so at pre-make stage. Often this way used to generate system-dependent header files.